# how to access [object HTMLTableCellElement]

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to make `[object HTMLTableCellElement]` into a string to use it in my HTML site?

Have tried `.innerHTML`, `.toString()`

`Console.log` prints it out without issues, only when trying to implement into HTML it comes out as `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`

Comment: You're probably trying to do `someElement.innerHTML += cellElement`. You should probably be doing `someElement.appendChild(cellElement)`

Comment: ` table.innerHTML = "";` `table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);`

These are my codes. Are these the problem? @VLAZ

Comment: SHOW YOUR CODE. Hard to help to see what you are doing wrong without the actual code.

Comment: i have edited the question @epascarello

Comment: Your code is not going to work because onload fires asynchronously.

Comment: I have made a new function and called this current function in its onload, even then, it still gives me a  `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`@epascarello

Comment: unclear how you are getting a cell, I see no TD elements in that code. Is table actually a table?

Comment: `    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="restaurantTable">
        </div>`

This is how I call it in the main page if this helps at all @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems with asychronous loading. And you are also going to append things out of order. Personally I would use fetch and promise all

```
function displayRestaurants() {
  var table = document.getElementById("restaurantTable");
  table.innerHTML = "";

  var promises = restaurant_array.map(function(restaurant) {
    return fetch('/averagepriceratings/' + restaurant._id)
      .then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        var average = json[0]['avg(priceRating)']
        var logo = restaurant.logo;
        var name = restaurant.name;
        var tags = [restaurant.priceCategory, restaurant.cuisineCategory, restaurant.areaCategory].join(', ');
        var cell = "<div>" + tags + "</div>";
        return cell
      });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(htmlStrs) => {
    table.innerHTML = htmlStrs.join('');
  });

}
```